# Effect of Scale of Data and Objective Function in the Convergence of Gradient Descent

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

One way to tune step size in gradient descent is via backtracking line search.

> backtracking line search (with parameters α ∈ (0, 1/2), β ∈ (0, 1))
>
> starting at $t = 1$, repeat $t := \beta t$ until $f(x + t\Delta x) < f(x) + \alpha t\nabla f(x)t\Delta x$

There are suggestions about what range of values to use for $\alpha$ and $\beta$, however, none of these discuss the scale of either data or loss function.
The question is shouldn't range of values of data and $f$ have conceptually  some effect in selecting $\alpha$ and $\beta$?
Is it assumed that data is normalized? How about objective value $f$?

Comment: Normalization for $f$ does not have sense, since for the backtracking with $\gamma f$ you will get the same stopping criteria. The smaller parameter $\beta$ the less iterations of backtracking you will make. On the other hand, smaller $\beta$ provides you a smaller step size. Also from the stopping criteria it follows that larger $\alpha$ is preferable.

Comment: How about normalizing $x$?

Comment: If you mean just taking $\gamma x$ for some $\gamma$ then for optimization problem this does not have sense as well: gradient descent will give you the same iterates.

Comment: No. I do not believe so... As for f, you could simply scale f  by d and then $\alpha$ would be effectively shrinked. Scaling x, has the same effect.